# Error handling while api limit exceeds in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm new to ReactJs, this is the code for fetching data from truepush api.

```
export const getAllCampaign = () => {
    return fetch(`https://api.truepush.com/api/v1/listCampaign/1`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `${TOKEN}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This api has limit, once the limit gets exceeds it shows an error of "campaigns.map not a function" at this place :

```
    const allData = campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
        ...campaign,
        ...stats[i].data
    }));
```

Here is my full code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {getAllCampaign, loadStats} from "../helpers/coreapihelpers";

const TableRow = () => {

    const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = useState([]);
    const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);

    const loadAllCampaigns = () => {
        getAllCampaign()
            .then(data => { setCampaigns(data.data) })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    };

    const loadAllStats = () => {
        loadStats()
            .then(data => { setStats(data) })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       loadAllCampaigns();
       loadAllStats();
    }, [])

    const allData = campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
        ...campaign,
        ...stats[i].data
    }));

    console.log(allData);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12">
                    <div className="table-responsive" data-pattern="priority-columns">
                        <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sr. No</th>
                                <th>Campaign Id</th>
                                <th>Campaign Name</th>
                                <th>Campaign Status</th>
                                <th>Reach</th>
                                <th>Sent</th>
                                <th>Delivered</th>
                                <th>Views</th>
                                <th>Clicks</th>
                                <th>Unsubscribers</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {allData.map(
                                (
                                    {
                                        campaignId,
                                        campaignTitle,
                                        campaignStatus,
                                        Reach,
                                        Sent,
                                        Delivered,
                                        Views,
                                        Clicks,
                                        Unsubscribers
                                    },
                                    index
                                ) => (
                                    <tr key={index}>
                                        <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                        <td>{campaignId}</td>
                                        <td>{campaignTitle}</td>
                                        <td>{campaignStatus}</td>
                                        <td>{Reach}</td>
                                        <td>{Sent}</td>
                                        <td>{Delivered}</td>
                                        <td>{Views}</td>
                                        <td>{Clicks}</td>
                                        <td>{Unsubscribers}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            )}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TableRow;
```

How can i show a simple h1 tag saying limit exceeds when api limit exceeds or fails to fetch data ?

Comment: Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). Like `{ campaign.map ? campaign.map(...) : <h1>oopsie</h1>}`

Comment: @ChrisG i tried this 
`const allData = campaigns.map ? campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
        ...campaign,
        ...stats[i].data
    })) 
        : <h1>hi</h1>`
but then TypeError: allData.map is not a function

Comment: Yes, because if the API limit has exceeded, `allData` is `<h1>hi</h1>` now. You could move the mapping from the main JSX into the code where you set `allData`, then simply use `{allData}` in your JSX. That way you don't have to check twice. Otherwise you'll again need `{allData.map ? allData.map(...) : allData}`

Answer (score 0):

`campaigns.map not a function` basically this error means that your campaigns is not holding any data or array data to map on it. *You can check it by consoling and debugging.*

Since api is giving error , either you can take a error state and check while the promise is resolved whether the response is success or not, if not then set error as true and in campaign it will be [] so, use `?.` which is chaining property to check if campaign is null or not if not then it searches for its key

```
  const allData = campaigns?.map((campaign, i) => ({
    ...campaign,
    ...stats[i].data
}));
```

and in return of component put conditional statement:

```
    return allData ?
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">....
        :<div>ERROR</div>
```

Comment: if chaining doesnt work, try to check (campaign.length >0) ? fetch the table: show error msg on browser.